# how to insert formula in the last row

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I created a UserForm to register patients and its working fine.

I tried adding a formula to it to concatenate the first middle last and second last name in column F but it's giving me an error. I can't get pass it. any suggestions?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Lista Pacientes")


'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


'check for a Valid patient name
If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Favor Introducir Nombre"
  Exit Sub
End If

    With ws

  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.TextBox10.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.TextBox11.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Me.TextBox12.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Me.TextBox13.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Formula = "=CONCATENAR(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(B" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & ")))"

End With


'clear the data
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""
Me.TextBox7.Value = ""
Me.TextBox8.Value = ""
Me.TextBox9.Value = ""
Me.TextBox10.Value = ""
Me.TextBox11.Value = ""
Me.TextBox12.Value = ""
Me.TextBox13.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus


Unload Me


End Sub
```

I'm getting runtime error 1004 in this obvious line

```
.Cells(iRow, 6).Formula = "=CONCATENAR(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(B" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(C" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(D" & iRow & "));SI(LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & "))="""";"""";"" "");LIMPIAR(ESPACIOS(E" & iRow & ")))"
```

The formula is in spanish the equivalent in english would be

```
CONCATENAR = CONCATENATE
LIMPIAR = CLEAN
ESPACIOS = TRIM
SI = IF
```

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the textbox values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because a lenguage issue, changed

```
.Cells(iRow, 6).Formula
```

to

```
.Cells(iRow, 6).FormulaLocal
```

Works like a charm